# Applescript only executing half my code

Tags: excel, applescript

I have two simple snips of code to script Excel, one gets the other sets.

If I place them in separate scripts they work as advertised. If I combine into a single script — in either order — only the first tell application "Microsoft Excel" code block executes. I'm noticing this when I have a Mail code block followed by an Excel code block in more complicated scripts, sometimes the second tell application block doesn't run (log statements won't log etc). Not always but enough times this occurs to be driving me batty. What is going on here?! Actually second question, this log statement doesn't return anything into the script events window, how come I sometimes see logs and sometimes don't.

```applescript
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
tell active sheet
    tell range "A1:B3"
        return value
        log ("Running")
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

```applescript
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
tell active sheet
    tell range "A1:B3"
        set value to {{11, 12}, {21, 22}, {31, 32}}
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

Here is a second example of seemingly the same issue:

```applescript
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
tell active sheet
    (* tell range "A1:B3"
        return value
    end tell *)
    tell range "B1:B10"
        set value to {{23}, {2}, {13}, {2}, {2}, {4}, {5}, {7}, {9}, {100}}
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

If I uncomment the three lines of code they will execute but the setter will not do it's thing anymore. Please help — going insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you

```
return aValue
```

The current routine will stop at that point and return the value. The rest of your code will not execute. 
Instead of return, you're gonna want to use something like

```
set x to its value
```

and then work with x

Comment: Thanks. One of the hundred weird things going on in AS for me today solved!